# Matching Polygons

Tags: c#, geometry, similarity, polygons

I'm working on a school project and my goal is to recognize objects. I started with taking pictures, applying various filters and doing boundary tracing. Fourier descriptors are to high for me, so I started approximating polygons from my List of Points. Now I have to match those polygons, which all have the same amount of vertices and all sites have the same length. More particular, I have two polygons and now I have to calculate some scale of similarity. This process has to be translation, rotation and scale invariant.

1. I tried turning and scaling one in different ways and calculate the distance between each pair of vertices, but this is very slow.
2. I tried turning the polygon in a set of vectors and calculate each angle of the corners and compare them. But this is also a bit slow.
3. I found an article called [Contour Analysis](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C). But i find this a bit difficult. In this article, firstly all vectors of each set are interpreted as complex numbers, so we only have two vectors with complex compounds. Then the cosine of both vectors is calculated. But the cosine is also a complex number and the norm of it is always 1 if both vectors are the same. So how does it make sense to interpret a set of vectors as one vector. I don't understand this practice.

Are there any other ways to compare two polygons or sets of vectors? Or can someone explain my 3rd try or do it with normal vectors?

I hope someone can help me out :-)

Comment: Post the code you need help with, and we will try to help.

Comment: I don't have any code of the 3rd solution. In the article he has multiple 2D vectors, each written as a complex number. But then he puts all them together to one n-dimensional vector of which each compound is a complex number (former 2D vector) and then he calculates the cosine of two  n-dimensional vectors with the formula you can find on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity. From that he doesn't get a cosine value as usual but a complex number, of which the real part is the  cosine and the norm is a scalar of similarity. But I don't understand that.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are well separated, you can characterize every contour using [Hu's moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment).

Description and basic math of image moments is rather simple and would be suitable for school project.

Comment: i think that is not what I'm looking for, but thank you.